# Return the index of the first element of a list which makes a passed function true

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

The `list.index(x)` function returns the index in the list of the first item whose value is `x`.

Is there a function, `list_func_index()`, similar to the `index()` function that has a function, `f()`, as a parameter. The function, `f()` is run on every element, `e`, of the list until  `f(e)` returns `True`. Then `list_func_index()` returns the index of `e`.

Codewise:

```
>>> def list_func_index(lst, func):
      for i in range(len(lst)):
        if func(lst[i]):
          return i
      raise ValueError('no element making func True')

>>> l = [8,10,4,5,7]
>>> def is_odd(x): return x % 2 != 0
>>> list_func_index(l,is_odd)
3
```

Is there a more elegant solution? (and a better name for the function)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020764 for Numpy-specific approaches focused on performance considerations.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426 if you only need the item itself, not an index.

Comment: Beside the point, but [there's no reason to use named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You could do that in a one-liner using generators:

```
next(i for i,v in enumerate(l) if is_odd(v))
```

The nice thing about generators is that they only compute up to the requested amount. So requesting the first two indices is (almost) just as easy:

```
y = (i for i,v in enumerate(l) if is_odd(v))
x1 = next(y)
x2 = next(y)
```

Though, expect a StopIteration exception after the last index (that is how generators work). This is also convenient in your "take-first" approach, to know that no such value was found --- the `list.index()` function would raise `ValueError` here.

Comment: This isn't obfuscatory - or at least, it's not any more obfuscatory than using `map(f, seq)` instead of `[f(x) for x in seq]` is.  In other words, it's idiomatic.  And like other idioms, it's not straightforward until it's part of your vocabulary.

Comment: just a reminder to catch `StopIteration` if the end condition might not be met.

Comment: Small hint: `next` accepts a second argument that will be returned in case of no match, instead of raising `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 24):

One possibility is the built-in [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) function:

```
def index_of_first(lst, pred):
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if pred(v):
            return i
    return None
```

It's typical to refer a function like the one you describe as a "predicate"; it returns true or false for some question. That's why I call it `pred` in my example.

I also think it would be better form to return `None`, since that's the real answer to the question. The caller can choose to explode on `None`, if required.

Comment: more elegant, better named, indeed

Comment: I think the OP wanted to emulate index's behavior of raising ValueError if the given value is not found.

Comment: +1 for enumerate which is a big favorite of mine. I can't remember the last time I actually had to maintain an index variable the old-fashioned C way in python.

Answer (score 18):

[Paul's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701404/4298200) is best, but here's a little lateral-thinking variant, mostly for amusement and instruction purposes...:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def __init__(self, pred): self.pred = pred
...   def __eq__(self, other): return self.pred(other)
... 
>>> l = [8,10,4,5,7]
>>> def is_odd(x): return x % 2 != 0
... 
>>> l.index(X(is_odd))
3
```

essentially, `X`'s purpose is to change the meaning of "equality" from the normal one to "satisfies this predicate", thereby allowing the use of predicates in all kinds of situations that are defined as checking for equality -- for example, it would also let you code, instead of `if any(is_odd(x) for x in l):`, the shorter `if X(is_odd) in l:`, and so forth.

Worth using?  Not when a more explicit approach like that taken by @Paul is just as handy (especially when changed to use the new, shiny built-in `next` function rather than the older, less appropriate `.next` method, as I suggest in a comment to that answer), but there are other situations where it (or other variants of the idea "tweak the meaning of equality", and maybe other comparators and/or hashing) may be appropriate.  Mostly, worth knowing about the idea, to avoid having to invent it from scratch one day.

Comment: Nice one! But what would we "name" X? Something like "Key" perhaps? Because it reminds me of l.sort(key=fn).

Comment: You could almost call it "Equals", so the line reads l.index(Equals(is_odd))

Comment: I think that what Alex (implicitly) suggested, `Satisfies`, is a good name for it.

Comment: @Robert, I do like Satisfies!

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but how do I express and use Satisfies in a generator that produces all the odd elements of list ref?  (Haven't gotten the hang of generators yet, I guess ...)

ref = [8,10,4,5,7]
def is_odd(x): 
    return x % 2 != 0
class Satisfies(object):
    def __init__(self, pred): self.pred = pred
    def __eq__(self, test_this): return self.pred(test_this)
print ref.index( Satisfies(is_odd))
#>>>3

Comment: Ouch!  That was supposed to be a code snippet! (Does this work?)

ref = [8,10,4,5,7] 

def is_odd(x): return x % 2 != 0 

class Satisfies(object): 

    def __init__(self, pred): self.pred = pred 

    def __eq__(self, test_this): return self.pred(test_this) 

print ref.index( Satisfies(is_odd)) 

#>>>3

Comment: BTW, next() is very appealing, but Cygwin and Pydee both are laggards and haven't advanced to 2.6 yet, AFAIK, so .next() will probably keep showing up for a while.

Comment: @behindthefall, give up on putting code in comments -- you've gotta post or edit an existing answer or question (and make sure to whine on the meta site, the more of us explaining this limit on comments is crazy the likelier Joel will ever heed us;-).  Anyway, unless you're using s/thing with built-in checks for == like index, `if x=Satisfied(p)` is just a weird way of sayinf `if p(x)`;-).  And yeah, even minor-version upgrades always lag (app engine is 2.5 too), but I've written my own easy `def next` for Py<2.6, post a question if you want me to show it!

Answer (score 6):

Not one single function, but you can do it pretty easily in Python 2:

```
>>> test = lambda c: c == 'x'
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x']
>>> map(test, data).index(True)
3
```

If you don't want to evaluate the entire list at once you can use itertools, but it's not as pretty:

```
>>> from itertools import imap, ifilter
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ifilter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(imap(test, data))).next()[0]
3
```

Just using a generator expression is probably more readable than `itertools` though.

Note in Python3, `map` and `filter` return lazy iterators and you can just use:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> next(filter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(map(test, data))))[0]
3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this evaluates the entire list - would be nice to have a solution that short-circuits, that is, returns immediately when finding the first match.

Comment: I think your `map().index(True)` will not work since this isn't a list but a map object

Comment: Indeed, you have to convert the map object into a list in order to use index: `list(map(test, data)).index(True)`

Comment: @astrochun In Python 2, `map()` returned a list. I've edited the answer to clarify that.

Comment: Fair point, but Python 2 has been deprecated. I know the original question originated so long ago

Answer (score 3):

Intuitive one-liner solution:

```
i = list(map(lambda value: value > 0, data)).index(True)
```

Explanation:

1. we use map function to create an iterator containing True or False based on if each element in our list pass the condition in the lambda or not.
2. then we convert the map output to list
3. then using the index function, we get the index of the first true which is the same index of the first value passing the condition.

Comment: This is by far the nicest looking approach, but it doesn't early stop once the condition is satisfied

Answer (score 2):

A variation on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701922/4298200). This avoids having to type `X` every time you want to use `is_odd` or whichever predicate

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __init__(self, pred): self.pred = pred
...     def __eq__(self, other): return self.pred(other)
... 
>>> L = [8,10,4,5,7]
>>> is_odd = X(lambda x: x%2 != 0)
>>> L.index(is_odd)
3
>>> less_than_six = X(lambda x: x<6)
>>> L.index(less_than_six)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some of my favorite tools that deserve more love ([`indexOf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.indexOf), [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress), [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)):

```py
from operator import indexOf

def list_func_index(lst, func):
    return indexOf(map(func, lst), True)
```

```
from itertools import compress, count

def list_func_index(lst, func):
    return next(compress(count(), map(func, lst)))
```

Or with your `ValueError`

```
from itertools import compress, count

def list_func_index(lst, func):
    for index in compress(count(), map(func, lst)):
        return index
    raise ValueError('no element making func True')
ist_func_index(l, is_odd))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=tVK9SgQxEAbLPMVYyCUQ4RTF4-BKaxuxETmW28kZzCZhMoH1WWyu0YfyacxmdxG1EAtThIRvvp8Z5uUtPvNj8IfDa2Zzuno_Ug42cL_ScLbUcKHhUsPVg2jRgE3b0LayV2sg5EweejiBczjewLIWMCaWBY1kPUtnE29N9rut9S320ulJQSkhhKHQQYhIDQcC28VADLXwxoiq9oOfWMPwV2sB5UwZJo7smigHVEMpVBpuKeNgNIaaHS0jcQguzZa70EXClHR5Zc9_svbYs5wFZOXL4vw1ifqvEGaY24CUG35NMXK-z23sprEJ4a5xGa-JAsmFD4AOO_RcZJ6s31ffOtLFZzvjxkyLMy_QBw)

Answer (score -1):

you could do this with a list-comprehension:

```
l = [8,10,4,5,7]
filterl = [a for a in l if a % 2 != 0]
```

Then filterl will return all members of the list fulfilling the expression a % 2 != 0. I would say a more elegant method...

Comment: Can you edit your answer to be more like the OP's function that has a list and function as parameters?

Comment: This is wrong.  It returns a list of values, not a single index.

Comment: filterl = [a for a in l if is_odd(a)]

Comment: I said that you can do this with a list comprehension and also that it returns a list. Just wanted to give a different option, because I'm not sure what the exact problem of bandana was.