# How to pick just one item from a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-2.x

I have a generator function like the following:

```
def myfunct():
  ...
  yield result
```

The usual way to call this function would be:

```
for r in myfunct():
  dostuff(r)
```

My question, is there a way to get just one element from the generator whenever I like?
For example, I'd like to do something like:

```
while True:
  ...
  if something:
      my_element = pick_just_one_element(myfunct())
      dostuff(my_element)
  ...
```

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Create a generator using

```
g = myfunct()
```

Everytime you would like an item, use

```
next(g)
```

(or `g.next()` in Python 2.5 or below).

If the generator exits, it will raise `StopIteration`.  You can either catch this exception if necessary, or use the `default` argument to `next()`:

```
next(g, default_value)
```

Comment: Note, it will only raise StopIteration when you try to use g.next() after the last item in g has been provided.

Comment: `next(gen, default)` may also be used to avoid the `StopIteration` exception. For example `next(g, None)` for a generator of strings will either yield a string or None after the iteration was finished.

Comment: in Python 3000, next() is __next__()

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin: Your comment is somewhat misleading.  In Python 3, you would use the second syntax given in my answer, `next(g)`.  This will internally call `g.__next__()`, but you don't really have to worry about that, just as you usually don't care that `len(a)` internally calls `a.__len__()`.

Comment: I should have been more clear. `g.next()` is `g.__next__()` in py3k. The builtin `next(iterator)` has been around since Python 2.6, and is what should be used in all new Python code, and it's trivial to backimplement if you need to support py <= 2.5.

Comment: I think [@kxr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1184933) provides quite good reasons (five years later, hence the lack of upvotes) for not explicitly bothering with `next()` and the `StopIteration` exception in [their excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35370041/260122). `itertools.islice()` is a real gem, nice and Pythonic, and one should not be afraid of the for loop in favor of one-liners.

Comment: @clacke: These "good reasons" are that it is "odd", "rarely used", "very low-level practice" and "non-pythonic".  It's easy to prove that "rarely used" is wrong.  The other "reasons" are simply stated without any reference or rationale, and I can't tell how kxr came to these conclusions.  In my opinion, the built-in `next()` is provided for exactly this purpose, so it's the natural function to use, and it is what most people use for this purpose.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The statement is that "Using next() *should* be very rare" (my emphasis). It's a matter of interpretation, but I think the intended meaning is not an observation on actual use, but on best practice. What's more pythonic is a matter of taste, of course. For my part, I agree with [@kxr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35370041/260122) that using the higher-level protocol makes for less obscure code, even though `next()` isn't *that* obscure. I'm grateful for the tip about the existance of `islice()`, which was exactly what I was looking for when I found this question.

Comment: I've found that for picking one item from a generator the `next(g, None)` syntax combines nicely with the walrus operator to proceed if the generator yields and item: `if (item := next(g, None)): print(item)`. This also combines nicely with `filter`, i.e. `next(filter(cond, iterable), None)`

Answer (score 36):

For picking just one element of a generator use `break` in a `for` statement, or `list(itertools.islice(gen, 1))`

According to your example (literally) you can do something like:

```
while True:
  ...
  if something:
      for my_element in myfunct():
          dostuff(my_element)
          break
      else:
          do_generator_empty()
```

If you want "*get just one element from the* [once generated] *generator whenever I like*"  (I suppose 50% thats the original intention, and the most common intention)  then:

```
gen = myfunct()
while True:
  ...
  if something:
      for my_element in gen:
          dostuff(my_element)
          break
      else:
          do_generator_empty()
```

This way explicit use of `generator.next()` can be avoided, and end-of-input handling doesn't require (cryptic) `StopIteration` exception handling or extra default value comparisons.

The `else:` of `for` statement section is only needed if you want do something special in case of end-of-generator.

## Note on `next()` / `.next()`:

In Python3 the `.next()` method was renamed to `.__next__()` for good reason: its considered low-level (PEP 3114). Before Python 2.6 the builtin function `next()` did not exist. And it was even discussed to move `next()` to the `operator` module (which would have been wise), because of its rare need and questionable inflation of builtin names.

Using `next()` without default is still very low-level practice - throwing the cryptic `StopIteration` like a bolt out of the blue in normal application code openly. And using `next()` with default sentinel - which best should be the only option for a `next()` directly in `builtins` - is limited and often gives reason to odd non-pythonic logic/readablity.

Bottom line: Using next() should be very rare - like using functions of `operator` module. Using `for x in iterator` , `islice`, `list(iterator)` and other functions accepting an iterator seamlessly is the natural way of using iterators on application level - and quite always possible. `next()` is low-level, an extra concept, unobvious - as the question of this thread shows. While e.g. using `break` in `for` is conventional.

Comment: This is way too much work for just getting the first element of a list result. Often enough I do not need it to be lazy but do not have a choice in py3. Is there not something akin to `mySeq.head` ?

Comment: in my opinion, the `for … break` pattern is bad because the intention of `for` is unclear until encountering the `break` at the end (and the problem here lies with that it must be placed at the end), so at least one should write a comment at the `for`; I would prefer to see a `with x in <generator>:` syntax

Comment: According to [PEP 3114](https://peps.python.org/pep-3114/), `next` was renamed for method definitions but the built-in method wasn't changed. In other words, `next(x)` is fine in Python 3, but `x.next()` won't work.

Answer (score 19):

Generator is a function that produces an iterator. Therefore, once you have iterator instance, use [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch the next item from the iterator.
As an example, use next() function to fetch the first item, and later use `for in` to process remaining items:

```py
# create new instance of iterator by calling a generator function
items = generator_function()

# fetch and print first item
first = next(items)
print('first item:', first)

# process remaining items:
for item in items:
    print('next item:', item)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can pick specific items using destructuring, e.g.:

```
>>> first, *middle, last = range(10)
>>> first
0
>>> middle
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> last
9
```

Note that this is going to consume your generator, so while highly readable, it is less efficient than something like `next()`, and ruinous on infinite generators:

```
>>> first, *rest = itertools.count()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's a convenient way to retrieve an arbitrary value from a generator.  The generator will provide a next() method to traverse itself, but the full sequence is not produced immediately to save memory.  That's the functional difference between a generator and a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
generator = myfunct()
while True:
   my_element = generator.next()
```

make sure to catch the exception thrown after the last element is taken

Comment: Not valid for Python 3, see the excellent [answer by kxr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35370041/260122).

Comment: Just replace "generator.next()" with "next(generator)" for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you scanning through these answers for a complete working example for Python3... well here ya go:

```
def numgen():
    x = 1000
    while True:
        x += 1
        yield x

nums = numgen() # because it must be the _same_ generator

for n in range(3):
    numnext = next(nums)
    print(numnext)
```

This outputs:

```
1001
1002
1003
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a short example of getting a single object from an iterator. If you know the properties of the object your looking for this will give it to you.

```py
obj = next((obj for obj in iterator() if obj.prop == match_prop), None)
if obj is not None:
    pass
```

Answer (score -4):

I believe the only way is to get a list from the iterator then get the element you want from that list.

```
l = list(myfunct())
l[4]
```

Comment: Sven's answer is probably better, but I'll just leave this here incase it's more inline with your needs.

Comment: Make sure that you have a finite generator before doing this.

Comment: Sorry, this has complexity the length of the iterator, while the problem is obviously O(1).

Comment: Wasting too many memory and process to suck from generator! Also, as @Seth mentioned before, generators are not guaranteed for, when to stop generating.

Comment: This is obviously _not_ the only way (or the best way if `myfunct()` generates a large number of values) since you can use the built-in function `next` to get the next generated value.