# Getting all arguments and values passed to a function

Tags: python

I have a Python function, `fetch_data`, that goes and hits a remote API, grabs some data, and returns it wrapped in a response object. It looks a bit like the below:

```
def fetch_data(self, foo, bar, baz, **kwargs):
    response = Response()
    # Do various things, get some data
    return response
```

Now, it's possible that the response data says "I have more data, call me with an incremented `page` parameter to get more". Thus, I'd essentially like to store "The Method Call" (function, parameters) in the response object, so I can then have a `Response.get_more()` which looks at the stored function and parameters, and calls the function again with (almost) the same parameters, returning a new `Response`

Now if `fetch_data` were defined as `fetch_data(*args, **kwargs)` I could just store `(fetch_data, args, kwargs)` in `response`. However I have `self`, `foo`, `bar` and `baz` to worry about - I could just store `(fetch_data, foo, bar, baz, kwargs)` but that's a highly undesirable amount of repetition.

Essentially, I'm trying to work out how to, from within a function, get a completely populated `*args` and `**kwargs`, including the function's named parameters.

Comment: Why not pass foo, bar, baz, and kwargs to Response() constructor so later call to response.get_more() already has those values?

Comment: Because that doesn't fix the problem - I'd still need to touch `Response` if I changed the signature of `fetch_data`.

Answer (score 174):

> Essentially, I'm trying to work out how to, from within a function, get a completely populated *args and **kwargs, including the function's named parameters.

How about saving the arguments via `locals()` at the beginning of the function?

```
def my_func(a, *args, **kwargs):
    saved_args = locals()
    print("saved_args is", saved_args)
    local_var = 10
    print("saved_args is", saved_args)
    print("But locals() is now", locals())

my_func(20, 30, 40, 50, kwarg1='spam', kwarg2='eggs')
```

It gives this output:

```
saved_args is {'a': 20, 'args': (30, 40, 50), 'kwargs': {'kwarg1': u'spam', 'kwarg2': u'eggs'}}
saved_args is {'a': 20, 'args': (30, 40, 50), 'kwargs': {'kwarg1': u'spam', 'kwarg2': u'eggs'}}
But locals is now {'a': 20, 'saved_args': {...}, 'args': (30, 40, 50), 'local_var': 10, 'kwargs': {'kwarg1': u'spam', 'kwarg2': u'eggs'}}
```

Hat tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137022/2829764

Comment: As of Python 3.5, this does not work with default arguments, at least not if they are None. Of course this is a different case, not using *args, **kwargs.

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.6.9

Comment: This is a great answer. Take care though that if you are working inside a class method, you will need to `pop` the `self` argument. (unless you need it)

Comment: @calder-ty From my expereince, you need to remove also `__class__`. Inside an `__init__` function of a class, I poped the `self` using `locals_ = locals().copy()` and `locals_.pop("self")`. But there still remained `__class__`

Answer (score 54):

Not something I'd do, but you could use [`inspect.signature`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) to introspect the arguments your method takes:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foobar(foo, bar, baz):
...     return inspect.signature(foobar)
... 
>>> foobar(1, 2, 3)
<Signature (foo, bar, baz)>
```

The returned [`Signature` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) has an ordered collection of parameters (the [`.parameters` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.parameters)) which can then be used together with `locals()` to produce a list of your argument values:

```py
>>> def foobar(foo, bar, baz):
...     sig, foobar_locals = inspect.signature(foobar), locals()
...     return [foobar_locals[param.name] for param in sig.parameters.values()]
...
>>> foobar(1, 2, 3)
[1, 2, 3]
```

However, you really only need such magic when doing advanced function decorators and the like. I think it's overkill here.

Answer (score 30):

I am not sure this is exactly what you want, but `locals()` provides a dictionary of local variables.

```
>>> def foo(bar, toto):
...     print(locals())
...
>>> foo(3,'sometext')
{'toto': 'sometext', 'bar': 3}
```

Answer (score 15):

I think a more Pythonic way is to turn your function into a generator, fetching and `yield`ing data for as long as the server keeps returning stuff.

This should result in neat code and would enable you to side-step all of the complexities of preserving the arguments across iterations (Python will magically do it for you :-))

Comment: This is definitely one of the cases being a lot more suitable for such application. And that way also gives OP opportunity to add `get_more` method returning results from next series of generator iterations.

Comment: The thing is there are many cases where you wouldn't care that there was more data, thus returning a generator feels a little unnatural; having a `next()` / `get_more()` on the returned object feels far more appropriate...

Comment: @KristianGlass: I am not sure I follow. You can just as easily call (or not call) `next()` on the generator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741243/how-to-pick-just-one-item-from-a-generator-in-python

Comment: Yes, but it would wrap the response object; generators are essentially wrappers, I basically want a generator-y mixin of sorts

Answer (score 12):

[`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) is deprecated since version 3.0. Use [`signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) and Signature Object, which provide a better introspecting API for callables.

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def foo(a, *, b:int, **kwargs):
...     pass

>>> sig = signature(foo)

>>> str(sig)
'(a, *, b:int, **kwargs)'

>>> str(sig.parameters['b'])
'b:int'

>>> sig.parameters['b'].annotation
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 12):

I believe the method to choose is `getcallargs` from `inspect` as it returns real arguments with which function will be invoked. You pass a function and args and kwargs to it (`inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kwds)`), it will return real method's arguments used for invocation, taking into consideration default values and other stuff. Have a look at an example below.

```
from inspect import getcallargs

# we have a function with such signature
def show_params(first, second, third=3):
    pass

# if you wanted to invoke it with such params (you could get them from a decorator as example)
args = [1, 2, 5]
kwargs = {}
print(getcallargs(show_params, *args, **kwargs))
#{'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 5}

# here we didn't specify value for d
args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
kwargs = {}

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# but d has default value =7
def show_params1(first, *second, d = 7):
    pass


print(getcallargs(show_params1, *args, **kwargs))
# it will consider b to be equal to default value 7 as it is in real method invocation
# {'first': 1, 'second': (2, 3, 4), 'd': 7}

# ----------------------------------------------------------
args = [1]
kwargs = {"d": 4}

def show_params2(first, d=3):
    pass


print(getcallargs(show_params2, *args, **kwargs))
#{'first': 1, 'd': 4}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs

Answer (score 7):

```
import inspect

def f(x, y):
    print(
        inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
    )

f(1, 2)
```

Result:
`ArgInfo(args=['x', 'y'], varargs=None, keywords=None, locals={'y': 2, 'x': 1})`

Comment: Per the docs: "Note This function was inadvertently marked as deprecated in Python 3.5."
docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

Answer (score 1):

kwargs won't have 'foo', 'bar' or 'bad' as keys, so you can add those entries (w/ their values) to kwargs and just store (fetch_data, kwargs).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest/cleanest (...ughhh "pythonic") way would be to just use a decorator function... no need to use "inspect" or iterate over locals() -- just grab them directly from the decorator function. Try something like:

```
def call_info(func: callable):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Calling {func} with args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@call_info
def test_func(name, *args, size: int = 2, cheese: bool = True, **kwargs):
    print('nothing to see here...')
    print(f'but if you wanted to know.... name={name}, args={args}, size=size}, cheese={cheese}, kwargs={kwargs}')

test_func(44)
test_func(name='hello', size=4, cheese=False)
```

would print something like this:

```
Calling <function test_func at 0x0000015614079E40> with args: (44,), kwargs: {}
nothing to see here...
but if you wanted to know.... name=44, args=(), size=2, cheese=True, kwargs={}
Calling <function test_func at 0x0000015614079E40> with args: (), kwargs: {'name': 'hello', 'size': 4, 'cheese': False}
nothing to see here...
but if you wanted to know.... name=hello, args=(), size=4, cheese=False, kwargs={}
```

You can add the @call_info decorator to any methods/functions you wish to view the passed variables. Do whatever you like to the variables, before/after the main function call... just modify the wrapper.

there's a pretty good link describing how to use decorators here:

https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/

also described in the python documentation:

https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/glossary.html#term-decorator

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def my_func(a, *args, **kwargs):
    v = locals()
    allargs = [v[i] for i in my_func.__code__.co_varnames if i in v and i not in ('args','kwargs')]
    allargs.extend(args)
    return allargs, kwargs
```

List allargs combines required and optional arguments. The code has to be placed at the beginning of function, at least v = locals().

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def fun(a,b,c):
...   print(locals())
... 
>>> fun(1,2,3)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Note, you should save `locals()` in some variable inside function right after def statement. Because if you have additional variables inside functions, they will be in `locals()` too.