# How to unpack **kws in format for python

Tags: python-3.x

In python, I want to create logging function such as returning function's name, its arguments,and the value of function. The output I want with sys.stderr like 

`"test: f(arg='1', arg2='a')\ntest: f -> '1a'"`

The code is like below
```

```
def log(prefix):
def decorator(func):
  @functools.wraps(func)
   def wrapper(*args, **kws):
     code *here
    return wrapper
 return decorator
@log
function(arg="1", arg2="a")
 return arg + arg2
```

```

I thought of some code like below, but it won't work especially at arg="1" arg2="a". I dont know how to unpack kws arguments ( dict here) at just one time.

1.

```
print("{}: {}({})\n{}: {} -> {}".format(prefix, func.__name__, kws, prefix, func.__name__, func(**kws)), file=sys.stderr)
```

2.

```
print("{}: {}({})\n{}: {} -> {}".format(prefix, func.__name__, **kws, prefix, func.__name__, func(**kws)), file=sys.stderr)
```

If you are familiar with this, could you give me some solutions or hint?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10724495/3814202) may have some useful tools.  I don't really understand what you're doing with `func(**kws)`, I think you're calling the function twice here?  Anyway, something like `",".join("{0}={1}".format(arg, kws[arg]) for arg in kws)` might also be useful here.  AKA it's probably easier to just iterate through things