# python - where can I look up the arguments of types.FunctionType?

Tags: python, types, arguments

I am new to Python and wonder where can I can all the available arguments for the `FunctionType` in the `types` package?

I can found the related source code in here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/types.py

But I don't find clear definition of `FunctionType`.

Comment: Type `help(FunctionType)`

Comment: help is a great method, but its not when you want to get it programmatically. Although your answer is a solution also.

Answer (score -1):

use `inspect.getargspec`

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> def foobar(foo, bar, baz):
...     return inspect.getargspec(foobar)
... 
>>> foobar(1, 2, 3)
ArgSpec(args=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

check this for reference:

- [getting all arguments and values passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724495/getting-all-arguments-and-values-passed-to-a-function)