# python networkx: How to get a random path?

Tags: python, networkx

In the networkx there is such a function

```
nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=0,target=5)
```

it returns all the paths, but if there are a lot of possible paths, it will work very long.

How can one immediately get just any path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not produce *all* paths, it returns a generator that may be exhausted to obtain *all* paths. The distinction is not nit-picky: it is precisely how we can answer your question. From the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), `all_simple_paths` already uses a depth-first search (this is what you want). We can then do the following,

`path = next(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=5))`

Which will raise a `StopIteration` if no path exists. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741243/how-to-pick-just-one-item-from-a-generator-in-python) for more details.

Comment: Is this solution random though ?

Answer (score -1):

For example:

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.complete_graph(4)
paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=3))
print paths
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3]]

# get a random idx
idx = random.randint(0, len(paths))
print paths[idx]
# [0, 3] may be

# print all  path it
for path in paths:
    print path
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, your solution includes first calling `nx.all_simple_paths` which is precisely what OP wanted to avoid