# Alternative to list comprehension if there will be only one result

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm starting to get used to list comprehension in Python but I'm afraid I'm using it somewhat improperly.  I've run into a scenario a few times where I'm using list comprehension but immediately taking the first (and only) item from the list that is generated.  Here is an example:

```
actor = [actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName][0]
```

*(self.actors contains a list of objects and I'm trying to get to the one with a specific (string) name, which is in actorName.)*

I'm trying to pull out the object from the list that matches the parameter I'm looking for.  Is this method unreasonable?  The dangling [0] makes me feel a bit insecure.

Comment: Don't be afraid, It's not _that_ terrible :) One of the answers below that stop looping when the match is found are probably a better choice. `next(<generator_exp>)` is not too bad, but can become ugly if you try to make it work in 80 char lines. If you are looking up a bunch of actors by name it's going to be a better idea to make a `dict` so you can look them up directly.

Comment: Fortunately this is not something I am doing frequently or on large sets.  I'm fairly good with dictionaries, and will keep that technique in mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get the first item from an iterable matching a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You could use a generator expression and `next` instead. This would be more efficient as well, since an intermediate list is not created and iteration can stop once a match has been found:

```
actor = next(actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName)
```

And as [senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577088/senderle) points out, another advantage to this approach is that you can specify a default if no match is found:

```
actor = next((actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName), None)
```

Comment: More efficent -- and allows you to specify a default if no match is found.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you clarify "does not need to be consumed"?  Does that mean it will stop iterating once it finds the match?

Comment: Clarified wording in that regard.

Comment: Thank you.  This is definitely useful information and clearly superior to my method.

Comment: Loving Python more and more with these one-liners ! :]

Comment: Can you check for multiple conditions with this method?

Answer (score 29):

If you want to take the first match of potentially many, `next(...)` is great.
But if you expect exactly one, consider writing it defensively:

```
[actor] = [actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName]
```

This always scans to the end, but unlike `[0]`, the [destructuring assignment](https://dbader.org/blog/python-nested-unpacking) into `[actor]` throws a ValueError if there are 0 or more than one match.
Perhaps even more important then catching bugs, this communicates your assumption to the reader.

If you want a default for 0 matches, but still catch >1 matches:

```
[actor] = [actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName] or [default]
```

P.S. it's also possible to use a generator expression on right side:

```
[actor] = (actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName)
```

which may be a tiny bit more efficient (?).  You could also use tuple syntax on the left side — looks more symmetric but the comma is ugly and too easy to miss IMHO:

```
(actor,) = (actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName)
actor, = (actor for actor in self.actors if actor.name==actorName)
```

(anyway list vs tuple syntax on left side is purely cosmetic doesn't affect behavior)

Comment: You've probably seen this: `[a, b] = [b, a]` for swapping, though it's usually shown without brackets.  It's called "destructuring assignment", or "unpacking".  The brackets/parents on the left side are optional, but are needed for the single-element case.  The right side can be any python expression, in this case a list comprehension.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the terminology.  I've used packing/unpacking in other situations but have never used it with a single variable to force a single result.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function) has a custom `find()` function which works quite well, and a commenter there also linked to [this method based on generators](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function). Basically, it sounds like there's no single great way to do this — but these solutions aren't bad.

Comment: Interesting that there are blog posts on this subject.  Thanks for the overview, I had difficulty finding information on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd to this in a proper loop.

```
actor = None
for actor in self.actors:
    if actor.name == actorName:
        break
```

It's quite a bit longer, but it does have the advantage that it stops looping as soon as a match is found.

Comment: as does the `next()` solution.