# Python Dataframe find the file type, choose the correct pd.read_ and merge them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of files to be imported into the data frame

cdoe:

```
# list contains the dataset name followed by the column name to match all the datasets; this list keeps changing and even the file formats. These dataset file names are provided by the user, and they are unique. 
# First: find the file extension format and select appropriate pd.read_ to import
# second: merge the dataframes on the index

# in the below list, 
file_list = ['dataset1.csv','datetime','dataset2.xlsx','timestamp']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0:2:len(file_list)):
   # find the file type first
   # presently, I don't know how to find the file type; so 
   file_type = 'csv'
   # second: merge the dataframe into the existing dataframe on the index
   tdf = pd.DataFrame()
   if file_type == 'csv': 
       tdf = pd.read_csv('%s'%(file_list[i])))
   if file_type == 'xlsx': 
       tdf = pd.read_excel('%s'%(file_list[i])))
   tdf.set_index('%s'%(file_list[i+1]),inplace=True)
   # Merge dataframe with the existing dataframe
   df = df.merge(tdf,right_index=True,left_index=True)
```

I reached this far. Is any direct module available to find the file type? I found `magic` but it has issues while importing it. Also, suggest a better approach to merge the files?
**Update: Working solution**
Inspired from the @ljdyer answer below, I came with the following and this is working perfectly:

```
  def find_file_type_import(file_name):
    # Total file extensions possible for importing data
    file_type = {'csv':'pd.read_csv(file_name)',
                  'xlsx':'pd.read_excel(file_name)',
                 'txt':'pd.read_csv(file_name)',
                 'parquet':'pd.read_parquet(file_name)',
                  'json':'pd.read_json(file_name)'
                 }
    df = [eval(val) for key,val in file_type.items() if file_name
          .endswith(key)][0]
    return df
  df = find_file_type_import(file_list [0])
```

This is working perfectly. Thank you for your valuable suggestions. ALso, correct me with the use of `eval` is good one or not?

Comment: I do not understand the approach to the problem. Wouldn't it be sufficient to specify the file extension for each item in the list?

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano I updated my problem. True I can specify the file extensions but in reality the list keeps changing and even the file types. So, I am trying something that script can detect the file type and use appropriate import module.

Comment: I understand, but what if you have two files in the same folder but with different extensions? E.g. "dataset1.csv" and "dataset1.xlsx"? How do you distinguish them starting with "dataset1"? In your use case then do you guarantee the uniqueness of the file name regardless of the extension?

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano Yes! they are indeed unique irrespective of the file extensions. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file type is just the three or four letters at the end of the file name, so the simplest way to do this would just be:

```
if file_list[i].endswith('csv'):
```

etc.

Other commons options would be `os.path.splitext` or the `suffix` attribute of a `Path` object from the built-in `os` and `pathlib` libraries respectively.

The way you are merging looks fine, but I'm not sure why you are using percent notation for the parameters to `read_`, `set_index`, etc. The elements of your list are just strings anyway, so for example

```
tdf = pd.read_csv('%s'%(file_list[i])))
```

could just be:

```
tdf = pd.read_csv(file_list[i])
```

---

**(Answer to follow-up question)**

Really nice idea to use a `dict`! It is generally considered good practice to avoid `eval` wherever possible, so here's an alternative option with the pandas functions themselves as dictionary values. I also suggest a prettier syntax for your list comprehension with exactly one element based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008062/17568469) and some clearer variable names:

```
def find_file_type_import(file_name):
    # Total file extensions possible for importing data
    read_functions = {'csv': pd.read_csv,
                    'xlsx': pd.read_excel,
                    'txt': pd.read_csv,
                    'parquet': pd.read_parquet,
                    'json': pd.read_json}
    [df] = [read(file_name) for file_ext, read in read_functions.items()
        if file_name.endswith(file_ext)]
    return df
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. `.endswith` has actually inspired me to write complete answer and it is working perfectly. Please, have a look at my updated question. Thanks

Comment: Have added some comments on your added code to the answer - I hope it's useful.

Comment: This is quite helpful for me to understand and improve my skill. Really appreciate that. Yes! I heard previously here that `eval` is not a good practice. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) (or even just [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)) to retrieve the list of files from a part of their name. Since you guarantee the uniqueness of the file irrespective of the extension, it will only be one (otherwise just put a loop that iterates over the retrieved elements).

Once you have the full file name (which clearly has the extension), just do a [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) taking the last element obtained that corresponds to the file extension.

Then, you can read the dataframe with the appropriate function.

Here is an example of code:

```py
from glob import glob

file_list = [
    'dataset0',  # corresponds to dataset0.csv
    'dataset1',  # corresponds to dataset1.xlsx
    'dataset2.a'
]

for file in file_list:
    files_with_curr_name = glob(f'*{file}*')

    if len(files_with_curr_name) > 0:
        full_file_name = files_with_curr_name[0]  # take the first element, the uniqueness of the file name being guaranteed

        # extract the file extension (string after the dot, so the last element of split)
        file_type = full_file_name.split(".")[-1]

        if file_type == 'csv':
            print(f'Read {full_file_name} as csv')
            # df = pd.read_csv(full_file_name)
        elif file_type == 'xlsx':
            print(f'Read {full_file_name} as xlsx')
        else:
            print(f"Don't read {full_file_name}")
```

Output will be:

```
Read dataset0.csv as csv
Read dataset1.xlsx as xlsx
Don't read dataset2.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [pathlib](https://pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/pep428/) and a switch dict to call functions.

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


def main(files: list) -> None:
    caller = {
        ".csv": read_csv,
        ".xlsx": read_excel,
        ".pkl": read_pickle
    }

    for file in get_path(files):
        print(caller.get(file.suffix)(file))


def get_path(files: list) -> list:
    file_path = [x for x in Path.home().rglob("*") if x.is_file()]

    return [x for x in file_path if x.name in files]


def read_csv(file: Path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_csv(file)


def read_excel(file: Path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_excel(file)


def read_pickle(file: Path) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.read_pickle(file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    files_to_read = ["spam.csv", "ham.pkl", "eggs.xlsx"]
    main(files_to_read)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I see you have imported a module called `pathlib` Can I say your solution is more python way of doing it compared to my solution provided in the question?

Comment: I see in your solution, you are actually importing all files in a directory. correct? What if I have the files in different directories?

Comment: Yeah all files in dir that are csv, xlsx, or pkl. Its just an example you can use a predetermined list as well.

Comment: added an edit to find files but will be slow as it checks the file system you can speed it up by narrowing down the dir