# Search (position) in two-dimensional List

Tags: python, pyqt5

There is a list:

```
Aliances=[(1, 'Star Aliance'), (2, 'OneWorld'), (3, 'SkyTeam'), (4, 'Unknown'), (5, 'U-FLY Alliance'), (6, 'SkyTeam Cargo'), (7, 'WOW'), (8, 'Vanilla Alliance'), (9, 'Value Alliance'), (10, 'American Eagle'), (11, 'American Airlines'), (12, 'Sirius Aero'), (10012, 'ASL Aviation Holdings DAC')]
```

There is a number that is on this list:
`PK = 10012`

```
Aliances = S.QueryAliances()
print("Aliances=" + str(Aliances))
myDialog.comboBox_Alliance.clear()
if Aliances:
    for Aliance in Aliances:
        myDialog.comboBox_Alliance.addItem(str(Aliance[1]))
    PKs = []
    for PK in Aliances:
        PKs.append(PK[0])
    print("PKs=" + str(PKs))
    quantity = myDialog.comboBox_Alliance.count()
    index = PKs.index(A.Aliance)
    print("index=" + str(index))
    myDialog.comboBox_Alliance.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

Tell me please if anyone knows how to get "index" (position of PK=10012) directly from list "Aliances"?

[Link to Source Code on my GitHub](https://github.com/tsv19su254052/LoadWorkData-GUIs-and-Utilities/blob/67c2ae50ecff33983061df0e10cc3c688c16b26b/CorrectAirLine.pyw#L305)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not a two-dimensional list, but a list of tuples. However, the following should work:

```py
Aliances=[(1, 'Star Aliance'), (2, 'OneWorld'), (3, 'SkyTeam'), (4, 'Unknown'), (5, 'U-FLY Alliance'), (6, 'SkyTeam Cargo'), (7, 'WOW'), (8, 'Vanilla Alliance'), (9, 'Value Alliance'), (10, 'American Eagle'), (11, 'American Airlines'), (12, 'Sirius Aero'), (10012, 'ASL Aviation Holdings DAC')]

index = next((i for i, x in enumerate(Aliances) if x[0] == 10012), None)

print(index)
```

Output:

```py
12
```

This also returns `None` if no match is found. Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006873/17200348) solution.

Comment: If the solution worked, you should probably mark it as an answer or else the question stays open.

Comment: https://github.com/tsv19su254052/LoadWorkData-GUIs-and-Utilities/blob/3fa0f34a4e14a1c32a15aebfecb17be6ec777c58/CorrectAirLine.pyw#L321