# Finding the first list element for which a condition is true

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was looking for an elegant (short!) way to return the first element of a list that matches a certain criteria without necessarily having to evaluate the criteria for every element of the list. Eventually I came up with:

```
(e for e in mylist if my_criteria(e)).next()
```

Is there a better way to do it?

To be more precise: There's built in python functions such as `all()` and `any()` - wouldn't it make sense to have something like `first()` too? For some reason I dislike the call to `next()` in my solution.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition

Comment: Why must everything be an elegant one liner?  Create a function with a meaningful name and be done with it.

Comment: There's no `first` function in python, but it's easy to write: `first = next` ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope - looks fine. I would be tempted to re-write possibly as:

```
from itertools import ifilter
next(ifilter(my_criteria, e))
```

Or at least break out the computation into a generator, and then use that:

```
blah = (my_function(e) for e in whatever)
next(blah) # possibly use a default value
```

Another approach, if you don't like `next`:

```
from itertools import islice
val, = islice(blah, 1)
```

That'll give you a `ValueError` as an exception if it's "empty"

Comment: For someone who is seeing this for Python 3 , `itertools.ifilter` is now simply `filter` and is available in global namespace.

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
next((e for e in mylist if my_criteria(e)), None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use

```
next((e for e in mylist if my_criteria(e)), None)
```

or

```
next(ifilter(my_criteria, mylist), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

with for loop

```
lst = [False,'a',9,3.0]
for x in lst:
    if(isinstance(x,float)):
        res = x
        break

print res
```