# Python OR for list

Tags: python, list, or-operator, truthiness

In Python you can do

```
print (0 or None or False or "" or [] or "hello" or None or "bar")
```

which will print

```
hello
```

Can you do the same with a list? I.e. is there a Python function `foo` so that the following will also print `hello`?

```
print (foo([0, None, False, "", [], "hello", None, "bar"]))
```

Note that `bar` is not printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the first list element for which a condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962994/finding-the-first-list-element-for-which-a-condition-is-true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `next(filter(None, ...))` or `next(filter(bool, ...))` to find the first truthy value from a list:

```
def foo(l):
    return next(filter(None, l))
```

The [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) takes both a filter function, and an iterable, and returns an iterator that of the values from the iterable that pass the filter.

But when you set the filter function to `None`, then it is essentially the same thing as using `bool` as the filter function, so only values that [are *true*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) are allowed through. The [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) then gives you the first such value.

Demo:

```
>>> def foo(l):
...     return next(filter(None, l))
...
>>> print(foo([0, None, False, "", [], "hello", None, "bar"]))
hello
```

You *may* want to add the last value in `l` as a default for the `next()` call, in case there are only falsey values; `v1 or v2 or v3 or v4` would at least produce `v4` if none of the values are truthy, so the following does too:

```
def foo(l):
    return next(filter(None, l), l[-1])
```

Using `filter(None, ...)` is a *fraction* faster than `filter(bool, ...)` because the `filter.__next__` implementation [tests for `None` before it tests for `bool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/10354cbb5067b4719ba1c2d51d22314a644ed3e5/Python/bltinmodule.c#L593); this speed difference is very small and barely measurable (within a margin of error):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> t = [random.choice([True, False]) for _ in range(10 ** 6)]
>>> for ff in ('bool', 'None'):
...     count, total = timeit.Timer(f'deque(filter({ff}, t), maxlen=0)', 'from collections import deque; from __main__ import t').autorange()
...     print(f"{ff}: {total / count * 1000:8.4f} ms")
...
bool:  98.9971 ms
None:  95.7907 ms
```

Comment: I always get told I should use `filter(bool, ...)` instead of `filter(None, ...)` because it's more transparent.

Comment: @khelwood: `None` is literally the same thing as `bool`, actually, in the current implementation. Except that the test that checks if the first argument is `None` or `bool` is made each `__next__` iteration and if you use `None` then that test is *fractionaly* faster, resulting in a few % speed advantage for `filter(None, ...)`. It's not going to cost you more than a few microseconds per million filter iterations, so using `filter(bool, ...)` for documentation clarity is still a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce()` with the operator `or` in the `lambda` function:

```
from functools import reduce, partial

foo = partial(reduce, lambda x, y: x or y)

print(foo([0, None, False, "", [], "hello", None, "bar"]))
# hello
```