# Finding the exact match of many usernames stored in a variable while looping

Tags: python, json, regex, instagram-api

I have a code which sends usernames from an excel sheet as an input which is stored in a variable xy to an instagram API which in return gives the results. I load the URL to a JSON to get it in a json schema.

For example when my variable xy contains "shawn_123" the result from the API is:

```
{
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  [
 {
  "username": "shawn_123",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-  19/s150x150/11417456_1610194859266611_592197892_a.jpg",
  "id": "641567093",
  "full_name": "shawn ritz"
},
 {
  "username": "shawn_12345",
  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11324946_808347519273018_2073555780_a.jpg",
  "id": "2074312361",
  "full_name": "shawney"
}
]
}
```

And my code is

```
for r in range(1,10):
var=r,sheet.cell(row=r,column=1).value
xy=var[1]
myopener=Myopener()
url=myopener.open('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='+xy+'&count=1&access_token=641567093.1fb234f.a0ffbe574e844e1c818145097050cf33')
beta=json.load(url)
for item in beta['data']:
    print(item['id'])
```

As it is retrieving two outputs from a same username.

Note: I want a regular expression which searches the exact username from the json and save the user_id of only that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `username` matches before printing the id:

```
for item in beta['data']:
    if item['username'] == xy: # here check the username from your input
        print(item['id'])
```

Or, using `next` operator:

```
user_id = next((item['id'] for item in beta['data'] if item['username'] == xy), None)
```

Comment: So, you are saying I dont need any regular expression here?

Comment: You don't need to!

Comment: If you don't mind, can you give a brief explanation about the 2nd option using next operator which you have given. It would be really helpful. I meant how would it work in my loop? Now instead of printing the user_id, I am appending it to a list. >> if(conditions are true) then list.append(item['id'])

Comment: There already is a very good explanation how `next` works: ... _[best way to get the first item from an iterable matching a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition)_

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept the answer if it solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {"data":  [ {  "username": "shawn_123",  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-  19/s150x150/11417456_1610194859266611_592197892_a.jpg",  "id": "641567093",  "full_name": "shawn ritz"}, {  "username": "shawn_12345",  "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11324946_808347519273018_2073555780_a.jpg",  "id": "2074312361",  "full_name": "shawney" }]}

#### To get list
user_name = 'something'
print [i['username'] for i in d['data'] if i['username'] == user_name]

#### To get the username

print [i['username'] for i in d['data'] if i['username'] == user_name][0]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am actually trying to use the variables rather than the string itself, Because I have more than a 1000 usernames which i will be looping through.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"shawn_123".*?"id":\s"(\d+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO6kZ2/1)

**Explanation:**
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'"shawn_123".*?"id":\s"(\d+)"', re.DOTALL)
test_str = u"{\n\"meta\":  {\n\"code\": 200\n},\n\"data\":  [\n {\n  \"username\": \"shawn_123\",\n  \"profile_picture\": \"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-  19/s150x150/11417456_1610194859266611_592197892_a.jpg\",\n  \"id\": \"641567093\",\n  \"full_name\": \"shawn ritz\"\n},\n {\n  \"username\": \"shawn_12345\",\n  \"profile_picture\": \"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11324946_808347519273018_2073555780_a.jpg\",\n  \"id\": \"2074312361\",\n  \"full_name\": \"shawney\"\n}"
m = re.findall(p, test_str)
print m
#[u'641567093']
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex demo! I am new to it and needed just this to get to know about regular expressions.