# How to get a specific item from python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Barcode:

    def __init__(self, code, code_id = None):
        self.code = code
        self.id = code_id
```

I have a list of barcodes. How can I get a barcode with a specific id?

Comment: Is the list sorted by id?

Comment: Also, would you consider using a dict of id=>barcode to store the codes instead of a list?

Comment: each id is unique  generated using uuid.uuid4().hex , I just want to get it from the list : select barcode where barcode.id =something

Comment: Use a dict. This is a terrible use for a list. Also, consider using new-style classes. I doubt you should even be using Python 2, but you certainly should not be using it with old-style classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `BarcodeList` isn't sorted, I recommend the brutal approach:

```
def find_item(id):
    for item in BarcodeList:
        if item.id == id:
            return item
```

If it is sorted, see [What is the best way to get the first item from an iterable matching a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition)

PS: Why not use `dict`? It's born for doing this sort of job.

Comment: @Mitch I don't think this is an *obvious* duplicate, since the list is not necessary sorted. When it comes to the case where it's not sorted, can you provide a better approach? The brutal approach is added just for completeness.

Comment: @Mitch Well, your answer is better, and I really think you should post an answer here.

Comment: @Mitch You're right. Seems that answers below that question can help this OP a lot. Close vote cast.