# Python list finding with index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering how would you find the index of a element in a list if you only had part of it. For example

```
list = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "python"]
```

how would you find it if you only had `"pyt"` and needed the index for python???

Comment: It depends how you want a match to be decided.  For example, would `is` match "is" or "this" or both?

Comment: as @user2699 mentioned, what kind of result are you expecting: only the index of the first matched element or list of indexes by all matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward for loop:

```
def find_starts(val, my_list):
    for i, v in my_list:
       if v.startswith(val):
           return i
```

(If there is no match then this returns `None`.) This could be made neater with a list comprehension: see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is not 100% clear i assume you want to find all items that include the specified string.

```
alist = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "python"]

val = 'is'

def find_in_list(alist, val):
    res = []
    for e, v in enumerate(alist):
       if val in v:
           res.append(e)
    return res

find_in_list(alist, val)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however I was thinking this. ["Bob smith","Garry Taylor"] how would I find the index if I just gave it Bob??? Thx

Comment: alist = ["Bob smith","Garry Taylor"]
val = 'Bob'

Comment: dear @Richy this doesn't work as bob is not the whole element any way to get around it???

Comment: @adamtsang this works fine for me, the check is `if val in v` so Bob has just to be in Bob smith, and that's the case. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with a solution that work when some element are similar (for example `["foo", "asd", "foobar"]` and you have `"foo"` what would be detected as a correct element?)

The given function will return a list of indexes, which were identified as a correct element.

```
def find(foo, list):
   #Find similar elements
   similarElements = [e for e in list if foo in e]
   #Find their indexes
   indexes = [similarElements.index(i) for i in similarElements]
   return indexes
```

This solution isn't the fastest way, but an easy and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "python"]
>>> word = "python"
>>> y = [i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j == word]
>>> y
[5]
```

However, this is for the whole word, try this aswell.

```
>>> word = "py"
>>> for w in list:
...     if word in w:
...             sus.append(w)
...             print(sus)
...
['python']
```