# return matches if match

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I'm doing some pattern matching, and want to check whether part of a string appears in a list of strings.
Doing something like this:

`if any(x in line for x in aListOfValues):`

Is it possible to return the value of x in addition to the line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get the first item from an iterable matching a condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to retrieve the next match from a similar generator, with a `False` default. Note that this only returns the *first* match, evidently not every match.

```
match = next((x for x in aListOfValues if x in line), False)
```

Alternatively, an extremely simple solution could be to just deconstruct your current statement into a loop and return a tuple containing `x` as well as the line.

```
def find(line, aListOfValues):
    for x in aListOfValues:
        if x in line:
            return x, line
    return False, line
```

Comment: I would also add that `next` **only** returns the first item for which the condition is True and not all in case of multiple. at least not in the way it is used here.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I sort of interpreted that from the OP's question, but sure, I made that more clear.

Comment: Thanks, stuck with your "match" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by consuming the first item returned on match using `next`. Note that you have to protect against `StopIteration` exception if you're not sure you're going to find a pattern:

```
try:
    print (next(x for x in aListOfValues if x in line))
except StopIteration:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aListOfValues = ["hello", "hallo"]
line = "hello world"
#classic one
res = [x for x in aListOfValues if x in line]
print res
>>['hello']

# back to your case
if any(x in line for x in aListOfValues):
  print set(aListOfValues) & set(line.split())
>> set(['hello'])

match = set(aListOfValues) & set(line.split())
if match: #replace any query
  print match
>> set(['hello'])
```