# Python - Create tuple only if values are even

Tags: python

I have a working set of code that iterates through a string and searches for 2 relevant substrings. (shoutout to user @bulbus for the help!)

The code returns a list of tuples containing the index positions for the location of the next instance of each substring.

For example, if the strings and substrings looked like this:

```
sub_A = "StringA"
sub_B = "StringB"

s = "abcdefStringAghijklStringB"
```

Then the code returns the tuple `(6,19)` because that is the next index position where the two strings exist.

The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
[(m.start(),re.compile(sub_b).search(s,m.start()).start()) for m in re.finditer(sub_A,s)]
```

However, I want to change the code so that it only returns values to the tuple if the value is even.  I.E. in my example above the value "19" should not be a valid return.

As an example, let's say this is my new string:

`xxStringAStringBStringB`

I want the tuple to return `(2,16)`.  Because those are the next "valid" returns.

My code currently returns `(2,9)` but I want to skip the "StringB" at index 9 since it is an odd number.

Thoughts?  And thanks!!

Comment: You use the term "touple" extensively in your post.  Do you mean tuple?  Or is this something else?

Comment: Could you filter your final list to met your criteria?

Comment: @Jason Sperske:  I don't know if I can filter final list - because sometimes the next `StringA` is even, but the next `StringB` is odd.  In that case, I would need to ignore that `StringB` - but still use the `StringA` -- does that make sense?   .... @Tom Karzes:  typo - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> s = "abcdefStringAghijklStringB"                                                                
>>> [(m.start(),next((x.start() for x in re.compile(sub_B).finditer(s,m.start()) if x.start()%2==0),None)) for m in re.finditer(sub_A,s)]
[(6, None)]
>>> s='xxStringAStringBStringB'                                                                     
>>> [(m.start(),next((x.start() for x in re.compile(sub_B).finditer(s,m.start()) if x.start()%2==0),None)) for m in re.finditer(sub_A,s)]
[(2, 16)]
```

1. We use `finditer` to find all the `sub_B` after `sub_A`, but we need to bailout on first condition(even position) that satisfies
2. To do that we use next() call to bail out of the iteration. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-matching-a-condition) for more.
3. Now if we do not find a `sub_B` we want the iteration to return a default value in this case we chose `None`

Comment: Awesome.  next() seams to have done it!  Thanks again for all your help - and sorry for the delay on responding.

Comment: Spoke a little too soon.  banging my head against the wall about how I can get the next() interaction to work on the sub_A value as well.  I have it working with sub_B with the following full line:

`{(k,frameType[k]):[m.start(),len(frameType[k]) + next((x.start() for x in re.compile(frameType[k]).finditer(s,m.start()) if x.start()%2==0),None)) for m in re.finditer(k,s)] for k in frameType}` ... And have tried adding in a next() call for what I thought was the right location, but I get a return of TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator.... Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey can't seem to understand the issue. Do you want to add the detail in the Q or post a new question?

Comment: Decided to keep banging my head on the wall on this one, and finally have a solution!  ended up breaking it up onto multiple lines so I could visualize things a little better and see where my issue was.  Basically had to do with ensuring that my `if m.start() %2 == 0` was above the bulk of the loop... Thanks again so much!

Comment: @occvtech hey sorry that I did not follow up after your last question. Glad that it worked out for you.