# Find the last element in a row that matches a criterion

Tags: python, generator, iterable

In addition to this question "[Get the first item from an iterable that matches a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition)" I need the element one before the first match. Or fully equivalent: the last element in a row that matches a criterion. For example, if I need the last prime before the first non-prime in this list `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, the answer is 3. In case there is no such element the result could be None, an exception or a default value.

The straightforward solution is:

```
result = None
for x in numbers:
    if is_prime(x):
        result = x
    else:
        break
```

Is there a simple one-liner that solves the task?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a simpler way. My approach requires [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

1. Use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to cease iteration after a condition is no longer met to create a list of prime numbers until the first non-prime appears, i.e. `[2, 3]`
2. Then use `list[-1]` to get the last element of the list.
3. In case the list is empty, use `(list or [None])[-1]` so that it returns `None`

```py
import itertools
result = ([x for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda n: is_prime(n), numbers)] or [None])[-1]
```

---

[collections.deque()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```py
from collections import deque
result = (deque((itertools.takewhile(lambda n: is_prime(n), numbers)), maxlen=1) or [None]).pop()
```

Comment: This solution creates full list from a generator. Loosing the readability we loose the efficiency as well. The ideal solution should keep previous and current elements only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` and `islice` to construct an iterator with its own "future" available to it.

```
next(
    filter(
        lambda pair: isprime(pair[1]),  # The predicate applied to a pair
        zip(xs, islice(xs, 1, None))  # The iterator and its 'future'
    ),
    (None, None)  # A default pair in case no matches are found
)[0]  # Retrieve the 'current' entry from the matching pair
```

At each step you have a pair that you can think of as `(present, future)` and the predicate will be applied to `future`. At the end, we unpack the `present`, which represents the last non-matching entry in the iterator.

Note that this implementation, as presented, does not return the last entry in the list, because inherently if you zip `[a, b, c]` against its own shifted version you end up with one shorter than the other. You can use `zip_longest` (from `itertools`) to overcome this, but you'll need to handle the `fillvalue` (usually `None`) in your predicate.

---

As noted in a comment, this does not work for generators because it will consume the generator. Using a fold (`reduce` in Python), though, it becomes easier. First, in a more "Pythonic" presentation, the function looks something like this:

```
def fold(hist, cur):
    stop, prev = hist

    if stop:
        return hist

    if isprime(cur):
        return (True, prev)

    return (False, cur)
```

The first element of the tuple serves as a "stop" marker, and the second is our "needle." You can use this with reduce thus:

```
reduce(fold, xs, (False, None))[1]
```

That's not exactly a "one liner," but we can compress it into a `lambda`:

```
reduce(lambda z, x: (z if z[0] else ((1, z[1]) if isprime(x) else (0, x))), xs, (0, None))[1]
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Much closer to what I expected. This however will not work for generators, but if the expression `zip(xs, islice(xs, 1, None))` is substituted with something that accepts `xs` just one time, that would work.

Comment: You could do it with a fold. I will add it to the answer.