# Get a single key value from a list of maps

Tags: python-3.x

Given this map

```
r = {
  'items': [
    {
      'id': '1',
      'name': 'foo'
    },
    {
      'id': '2',
      'name': 'bar'
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get the 'id' for 'name'=='foo'. I have this:

```
Id = [api['id'] for api in r['items'] if 'foo' in api['name']]
```

But then `Id == ['1']`. I want it to = "1". I can do this:

```
Id = [api['id'] for api in r['items'] if 'foo' in api['name']][0]
```

But that seems like a workaround. Is there a way to write that in such a way as to pass only the value of `api['id']` rather than the value within a list?

Comment: Since, you are using list comprehension, your output for `Id` is supposed to be a list, so if there is only one element, then it would be this `Id == ['1']`. If you know that only one `Id` has the `name 'foo'`, then you can just use a for loop. So if your condition gets True, then Id will be saved into the `Id` variable, otherwise not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the first item from an iterable that matches a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details):

```py
Id = next(api['id'] for api in r['items'] if api['name'] == 'foo')
```

The added benefit is that the iteration will be stopped as soon as you encounter matching object, whereas your original code would process all of the original list and create a new one, only to extract its first element.