# Can I avoid the use of a loop when only one item to iterate?

Tags: python, django-models

I have a Django auction project (CS50 course assignment) and I have the following function in views.py:

```
def show_item(request, items):
items = Listing.objects.filter(item = items)

for item in items:
    ends = item.date + timedelta(days=7)
return render(request, "auctions/show_item.html",{
     "items":items, "ends": ends
    })
```

This allows me to display the item and its end date. My question is, since there is only one iteration in the loop (I'm showing a single item for auction on the template view), isn't there a cleaner way of doing

`ends = item.date + timedelta(days=7)` ?

(i.e. just need to obtain the item date field in the model)
Without the need of the for loop?
I tried : `ends = items.date + timedelta(days=7)`

but get an error?

Comment: What's the error you're getting

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: You're going to want to look at Python's `next` method, it's often used to find the first element that meet a criteria. You're also overwritting your original `items` parameter. I'd suggest renaming these variables to be more verbose.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition

Comment: I get: auctions.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
(in the console)

Comment: I'll look at the next method, thanks.   @ominug: Where is the indentation wrong?

Comment: The body of a function must be indented. We cannot see if the for loop belongs to `show_item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the first item with [0]:

```
ends = items[0].date + timedelta(days=7)
```

Comment: I would insert a condition before which checks the lengths of the array: `if len(items) != 1: raise RuntimeException("not exactly one element retrieved")`