# Divide values by lists of three and comparing elements in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some values coming from sensor. My task is to divide them into lists of three elements.  If two consecutive elements differ by at least 10, I should ignore the rest of the list.

From this:

```
values = [1,3,6,8,9,11,15,17,28,29]
```

I should get:

```
[1,3,6]
[8,9,11]
[15,17]
```

I've managed to divide values by list of three:

```
list_of_values = [1,3,6,8,9,11,15,17,28,29]
def divide(values, size):
    return (values[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(values), size))
for group in divide(list_of_values, 3):
    print(group)
```

But I can't figure out how to compare previous and next value like the task says.

Comment: breaks at 17 because 28 > 17 + 10

Comment: Clarified problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you break the list into triples, you need to find that break point.  Iterate through the loop, looking for that difference.  For ease of reading, I'm going to call your list `vals` instead of `list_of_values`.

```
for gap in range(1, len(vals)):
    if vals[gap] - vals[gap-1] >= 10:
        break
```

At this point, `gap` is the position of the frist element you exclude.

```
vals = vals[:gap]
```

Now you're ready to split your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach. You can find the absolute difference between consecutive elements using a list comprehension,

```
diff = [abs(values[i+1]-values[i]) for i in range(len(values)-1)]
```

The you can find occurrence of the first difference greater than 10 using a generator, which is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701211/python-return-the-index-of-the-first-element-of-a-list-which-makes-a-passed-fun),

```
ind = (i for i,v in enumerate(diff) if v >= 10).next()
lst = values[:ind+1];
```

`lst` is now your shortened list - i.e. list until and not inclusive the first value different by 10.

Finally, using an approach from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) the shortened list `lst` can be split into chunks smaller or equal to 3,

```
n = 3
print [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip and slicing to pair consecutive elements of a list:

```
import itertools
diff_less_than_10 = ((a - b < 10)
                     for a, b in zip(list_of_values[1:], list_of_values))
end = 1 + sum(itertools.takewhile(bool, diff_less_than_10))
groups = divide(list_of_values[:end], size)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate where to the `index` of where to **stop** the `chunking`:

```
stp = [i for i in range(len(values)-1) if values[i]+10 < values[i+1]] [0]
```

then `chunk` to this `index`:

```
[values[:stp+1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, stp, 3)]
```

which `outputs`:

```
[[1, 3, 6], [8, 9, 11], [15, 17]]
```