# Deleting an object from a list?

Tags: python, csv, sorting, object, del

So I am still a beginner programmer who has been tasked with sorting objects created by a csv file with the attributes lname, fname, gender, age (in that order) and sort them by the lname attribute. I have achieved this, however I now need to delete one of the objects (I chose a random one to test) and this is what I have so far:

```
class FitClinic:
    def __init__(self, lname, fname, gender, age):
        self.lname = lname
        self.fname = fname
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = int(age)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Customer has been deleted")

    def get_lname(self):
        return self.lname

    def get_fname(self):
        return self.fname

    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

fh=open('fit_clinic_20.csv', 'r')
fh.seek(3)
listofcustomers=[]
for row in fh:
    c = row.split(",")
    listofcustomers.append(FitClinic(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]))

sorted_list=sorted(listofcustomers,key=lambda x: x.get_lname())

for x in sorted_list:
    if x.get_lname()==("Appleton"):
        del x
    print(x.get_lname(),x.get_fname(),x.get_gender(),x.get_age())
```

now it obviously doesnt work and I need some help.

Answer (score 4):

`del x` just deletes the temporary variable `x`, it has no effect on the list. You need to use `del listofcustomers[pos]`, but first you have to find the position in the list.

```
try:
    pos = next(i for i,v in enumerate(listofcustomers) if v.get_lname() == "Appleton")
    del listofcustomers[pos]
except StopIteration:
    pass // Ignore if not found
```

See [Python: return the index of the first element of a list which makes a passed function true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701211/python-return-the-index-of-the-first-element-of-a-list-which-makes-a-passed-fun) for numerous ways to find the index of an element that matches a criteria.

Comment: Since you don't use the return from `pop`, `del listofcustomers[pos]` seems the more direct (and slightly faster) solution. `del` works for deleting by index or deleting attributes, not just raw top level names.

Comment: Probably doesn't make too much difference but that does seem more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This example is better with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) since it removes all clinics where `lname` is `Appleton`:

```
sorted_list = list(filter(lambda c: c.get_lname() != "Appleton", sorted_list))
```

If you want to remove only the first one, use [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507839/3150271).

This is the same as a list comprehension, which Python is better at optimizing:

```
sorted_list = [c for c in sorted_list if c.get_lname() != "Appleton"]
```

Comment: If you need a `lambda` to use `filter`, it's going to be slower than an equivalent listcomp that doesn't need it; `sorted_list = [c for c in sorted_list if c.get_lname() != "Appleton"]` is both faster and more concise (as well as more "Pythonic" if you listen to the BDFL, who hates `filter` in general).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right. `filter` can be clearer, but a list comprehension would be better here.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an item from a list with list comprehension:

```
sorted_list[:] = [x for x in sorted_list if not(x.get_lname()==("Appleton"))]
```

A working example:

```
class FitClinic:
    def __init__(self, lname):
        self.lname = lname

    def __del__(self):
        print("Customer has been deleted")

    def get_lname(self):
        return self.lname

# Create example
sorted_list = [FitClinic('a'), FitClinic('b'), FitClinic('c'), FitClinic('Appleton')]
sorted_list[:] = [x for x in sorted_list if not(x.get_lname()=="Appleton")]
```

Now sorted_list is.

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Might I suggest `x.get_lname() != "Appleton"` rather than `not(x.get_lname()=="Appleton")`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, you can use that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this:

```
for x in sorted_list:  # Loops through Customers in List
    if x.get_lname() == "Appleton":  # Check if the last name is Apple
        sorted_list.remove(x)  # Remove each from the list, Pretty self explanatory
    else:  # you only want to print if the last name is not APppleton
        print(x.get_lname(), x.get_fname(), x.get_gender(), x.get_age())
```

`.remove` removes an object from a list so you do not need to track the index of the loop.
Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) w3schools tutorial for more list operations

Comment: editing a list while iterating over it is asking for trouble.