# Get the length of certain values from list

Tags: python, list

I would like to get the length of certain values in a `list` like:

```
lst=['ID_CYTY', 'CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'NAME', 'P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W', 'NZ', 'EG', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS', 'RUT']
```

I just have another list like:

```
lst2=['P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W']
```

I would like to get the length of the values before and after `lst2` that are inside `lst` but the issue here is that `lst` could change in length from `ID_CITY` to `NAME` and `NZ` to `RUT`, I mean it could have more or less strings after `P` to `W`. Also, do not have to use the `names` of the strings because they could be different from the 0 index to the last index, example:

```
lst=['CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'A1', 'P', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'W', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'IN', 'NZ', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS']
```

I believe it could be done getting the `length` of the `lst2` and then doing some list indexing to get `lengths` inside `lst`.

The `lst2` it could have theirs strings mixed but it doesn't matter because it must have the same extension from `P` to `W` no matter if starts or ends with those strings.

Note: I would like to get the values before and after `lst2` in `lst` in individual list.

What I mean with before and after `lst2` inside `lst` is:
In the first case it would be:
The `length` before `P` to `W`:

```
9
```

the `length` from `NZ` to `RUT`:

```
9
```

But this could be different just how I mentioned before.

Comment: ```python  
lst2 = list(filter(lambda n: len(name) <= 3, lst))
```

Comment: What do you mean by before and after `lst2`. Please add the input and the corresponding output? Also include any code you have written

Comment: your question is very unclear what do you actually want in the end?

Comment: @DaniMesejo It looks like `lst2` is a sublist of `lst`, so he wants the parts of `lst` outside that sublist.

Comment: but, what's the thing with the new items in the list, that still confuses me. @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar Yes. Thanks for all your comments. What I want are the lengths before an after `['P':'W']` in individual variables. Hope to be clearer.

Comment: so initially he's given two list

Comment: @MetalJacket Why P and W?

Comment: @coderoftheday What do you mean by new items? I think he's just saying that the lists can vary, you shouldn't look for those specific strings.

Comment: @DaniMesejo `P` is the first element of `lst2`, `W` is the last.

Comment: @MetalJacket has your question been answered now?

Comment: Not yet, because I do not need to specify any name index and specify index position because they could be mixed @coderoftheday

Comment: what are we to use to figure out what the index should be?

Comment: What I was thinking is first get the `len(lst2)` and then do some string indexing to get the first and last values in differents variables. The `len` of `lst2` always would be a section or slide of lst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Python: return the index of the first element of a list which makes a passed function true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701211/python-return-the-index-of-the-first-element-of-a-list-which-makes-a-passed-fun) for how to find the index in a list of the first element that matches a condition.

In this case, the length of the list before `lst2` is the index of the first element that's in `lst2`.

```
before = next(i for i,v in enumerate(lst) if v in lst2)
```

To get the length of the list after `lst2`, do the same thing but reverse `lst` first.

```
after = next(i for i,v in enumerate(lst[::-1]) if v in lst2)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but there is an issue when index are mixed. I mean, when `lst2` have  'A1', 'P', it counts more if all is mixed. That's the other possibility that could happen here. The length of lst2 always will be inside lst but the index it could be mixed @Barmar

Comment: I thought the order of elements in `lst2` are the same as in `lst`, so it's always the first and last that it has to look for.

Comment: Any other idea? @Barmar

Comment: Hi @Barmar. I'm facing new issues when `lst` have `'A1, 'Ps, 'PRz'`  it gives me a different length in `before`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#lst=['ID_CYTY', 'CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'NAME', 'P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W', 'NZ', 'EG', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS', 'RUT']
lst=['CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'A1', 'P', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'W', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'IN', 'NZ', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS']
lst2=['P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W']

for i in lst:
    if i in lst2:
        start = lst.index(i)
        break
for i in lst[::-1]:
    if i in lst2:
        end = lst.index(i)
        break

print(len(lst[:start]))
print(len(lst[end:-1]))
```

Now even if both lists changed it finds the first and last value to calculate from

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
start = lst.index(lst2[0])
```

This will give you the position, in lst, of the first value in lst2

```
end = lst.index(lst2[-1])
```

This will give you the position, in lst, of the last value in lst2

```
print(len(lst[0:start]))
print(len(lst[end:-1]))
```

This prints the lengths between the values

Comment: He just wants the lengths, so they're `start` and `len(lst) - end`

Comment: Yes. How can I get it using `lst2`? @Barmar

Comment: `[end:-1]` should be `[end+1:]`

Comment: @Barmar It works with start but not using this `lst.index(lst2[-1])` the output is 23

Comment: @MetalJacket That's why you have to subtract: `len(lst) - lst.index(lst2[-1])`

Comment: @Barmar yes 23 is the position in lst. I use that to show where the start of the values are

Comment: The code outputs 9 and 9 which is what he wanted in his example

Answer (score 0):

This does what comment *'What I was thinking is first get the len(lst2) and then do some string indexing to get the first and last values in differents variables. The len of lst2 always would be a section or slide of lst. –'* says.

```
lst=['ID_CYTY', 'CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'NAME', 'P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W', 'NZ', 'EG', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS', 'RUT']
lst2=['P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W']

legnth_1= len(lst[:lst.index(lst2[0])])
legnth_2 =  len(lst[lst.index(lst2[-1])+1:])

print(legnth_1)
print(legnth_2)


>>> 9
>>> 9
```

Comment: I don't think he wants the combined lengths, he wants the lengths of the parts before and after `lst2` separately.

Comment: Yes, and also I do not need to specify any name index because it could be mixed.

Comment: So how we meant to know where the index will be? what are we using to determine the index

Comment: Thanks for the updated. Finally, I think its working fine. I would try some other times but it seems work very well @coderoftheday

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=['ID_CYTY', 'CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'NAME', 'P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W', 'NZ', 'EG', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS', 'RUT']
lst2=['P', 'A1', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'IN', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'W']

start = lst.index(lst2[0])
end = lst.index(lst2[-1])

print(len(lst[:start]))
print(len(lst[end:-1]))

>>>
9
9
>>>
```

Even if the list changes it still returns the difference

```
lst=['CITY', 'ID_STATE', 'STATE', 'ID_COUNTRY', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'A1', 'P', 'PR', 'V', 'Z', 'M1', 'D1', 'R1', 'CPD', 'CA', 'W', 'ND', 'I', 'C', 'IN', 'NZ', 'LOS', 'TO', 'LS', 'EST', 'TR', 'OBS']

>>>
8
11
>>>
```

Comment: But what if `lst2` changes or their values get mixed?. I mean if not starts with `P` or ends with another string. @Alexander