# How do I find the index of an unknown value in python?

Tags: python, list

So basically I have a list like this -

```
[None,None,None,val]
```

and I don't know what `val` is. So how do I get the index of val (3) only knowing that it is not `None`

Comment: Iterate through the list until the item is not `None`?

Comment: Yes, but it would be better if it was in one line

Comment: Why would it be better?

Comment: There's probably a confusing way to do it using `reduce()`.

Comment: `max(a, key=lambda i: 0 if i is None else i)`. There may still be a better way of writing this or another way.

Comment: @shahkalpesh That doesn't work. WIth input `[None,None,None,3,5,2]` it returns 5, not 3.

Comment: It looks like that's the index of the last non-None value. I suppose that could be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Barmar: OP doesnt say that it can have multiple values.

Comment: @sr0812: You should now try to find the index of the value. You have the list functions to do it.

Comment: @sr0812 You can use that code along with `enumerate()`

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701404/786593 you can do `next(i for i,v in enumerate(a) if v is not None)`

Comment: A pretty bad one liner for you `[item is not None for item in [None,None,None,val]].index(True)` - this returns index of first non-None value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one line solution gives you the first value that is not None.

```
values = filter(lambda item: item is not None, mylist)
target_value = next(values)

print(target_value)
```

This returns the actual value, to get the index, look into this answer first comment which is:

```
next(filter(lambda item: item[1] is not None, enumerate(mylist)))[0]
```

Comment: OP wants the index not the item itself, so `next(filter(lambda item: item[1] is not None, enumerate(mylist)))[0]` seems more apt.

Comment: Yes. Didn't see that part. Will edit the response so that they look into your comment.