# I want to delete all the lists with length 1 at the beginning and end but not in the middle in python

Tags: python, list

Given a list of lists (i.e. a nested list), I want to delete all the inner lists with length 1 from the beginning and the end of the outer list. For example

> `d = [[3], [1,5], [3], [3,2,4], [8], [3]]` should become: `[1,5], [3], [3,2,4]`.

For the start of the list, I am using the following code:

```
i = 0
while len(d[i]) == 1:
    d.remove(d[i])
    n = n -1
```

and for the end, I use this code:

```
 while len(d[n-1]) == 1:
    d.remove(d[n-1])
    n = n - 1
```

where n = number of lists.

When I run this I get:

```
[[1, 5], [3, 2, 4]]
```

So it also removes the lists in the middle with length 1. How can I change the code so it does not do that?

So for an `n` number of lists, I want to remove all the lists at the beginning which have length 1 until there is one list that does not have length 1. I want to do the same for the end of the list.

Comment: Say if the length of the main list(`d`) is 100, then can you *technically specify* what is beginning and ending ? May be first 10?

Comment: So i meant i want to delete lists d[0] to d[i] where all the lists in that range have length 1 and list d[i+1] does not have length 1. The same at the end where i want to delete lists d[n] till d[n-j] where d[n] to d[n-j] are off length 1 and d[n-j-1] is not of length 1.

Comment: Note that `d.remove(d[n-1])` removes the _first_ occurrence of `d[n-1]`, which could easily be in the middle of the list

Comment: @MaartenKant - Can you please add 2 or 3 examples with expected output please?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the current answers involve repeated popping from the front of a list, which is slow.

Using the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1701211/17769815) to find the first and last index where a condition does not hold, we can find the start and end of the desired sublist in linear time. Then, we construct the slice using the found start and end indices. If the list contains only sublists of length 1, then our generators will raise a `StopIteration` -- to avoid this, we check ahead of time whether all of the lists are of length 1:

```py
if all(len(item) == 1 for item in data):
    result = []
else:
    start = next(i for i, v in enumerate(data) if len(v) != 1)
    end = len(data) - next(i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(data)) if len(v) != 1)
    
    result = data[start:end]

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[[1, 5], [3], [3, 2, 4]]
```

---

If you *really* need speed, you can skip the generators and the first pass check (this code has been improved from a suggestion by [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)):

```py
start = -1
for idx in range(len(data)):
    if len(data[idx]) != 1:
        start = idx
        break

end = len(data)
for idx in reversed(range(len(data))):
    if len(data[idx]) != 1:
        end = idx
        break

result = data[start:end + 1]

print(result)
```

which seems to perform better on my machine.

Benchmark code:

```py
import timeit

def bb1(data):
  if all(len(item) == 1 for item in data):
      result = []
  else:
      start = next(i for i, v in enumerate(data) if len(v) != 1)
      end = len(data) - next(i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(data)) if len(v) != 1)

      result = data[start:end]
  return result

def bb2(data):
  start = -1
  for idx in range(len(data)):
      if len(data[idx]) != 1:
          start = idx
          break

  end = len(data)
  for idx in reversed(range(len(data))):
      if len(data[idx]) != 1:
          end = idx
          break

  result = data[start:end + 1]
  return result


def fb(d):
  while len(d[0]) == 1:
      d.pop(0) # remove from head

  while len(d[-1]) == 1:
      d.pop() # remove from tail
```

Then,

```py
data = ([[3] for _ in range(100000)]) + [[3], [1,5], [3], [3,2,4], [8], [3]]

%timeit -n7 bb1(data[:])
%timeit -n7 bb2(data[:])
%timeit -n7 fb(data[:])
```

Output:

```py
7 loops, best of 5: 23.7 ms per loop
7 loops, best of 5: 13.1 ms per loop
7 loops, best of 5: 900 ms per loop
```

Comment: This code is [9.7 times slower](https://tio.run/##lZHBbsMgDIbvPIWbXUCiXdN00lSJJ0E5IOEoSAkg4mTb02eQ7NKtmlQOYGz/5vtF/KI@@GZd3RhDIiA3oiPGEk41qJ/raT84q6qKTWRynwKPn8QddCGBk7CA84B@HjEZQm4NGQGugwE9XwQcFNSCobdZWFJ7/fj/kIQLpgnt3v13XGach4JS6nrjuuUn2oIp2YQ0R1WVWm7Rumkl6Fq@lWOLG3mR1xK876m2YmIzfnls/KN3A@70@twKUBnixiAve4oh8rOAF0g4hgWhS2GEHo1ld7Jj/UD3W0bGDfcWnuGPyXni5fskFC/bXr@WUKzrNw "Python 3 – Try It Online") than code in my answer

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a closer look in a bit.

Comment: BTW, the current version is [30 times slower](https://tio.run/##jVLbSsNAEH3frxjXl8Rua5IqSCEPKgUFbxh9CkFWMqELubHZtl7w2@NsUq2VetmHhZk958zMma2fzawqx22rirrSBowqUBnGrh5OplenZxDCoed5FEbHl9MuYqfXt9OHi/PojkIe@@IwERCPu0sE4iARnEXTu/ubNYbDgG6CcNiDldQA1jr29ci@boPxhDOmsfFJqu9upLFGaRyWcc6ZykDmuZNj6SiDhQthCD5klQYbgiohlUa6EwZ0SGeeG1KKE4Z5g322MVLbZIlPxlE9V8DCcrGcF6ilQadTAapmKy1c2KEybkfHMiWyTfeY4e9CGheoG0x79HbJzWYtMO6anFCthDHZNEgdfwBonNdPN98SRrYI1qCZ12HGLZk0Xtc7eeMCqJtH1OFqzcztLA5@sHg5Uzn2A8Ze0jvcO5eO6qp2PBd2qZmiWiBkuipghjJlG7Shv4X3nWakyj@HS/@a6z9D1VqVxrG/R1i3AneV4VFeLdNqWU6IFmt/XwfdtrTFBXZfL6r@ykvctn0H)

Comment: @ForceBru I took a closer look at your benchmarks. The lists you're using are too small to expose the asymptotic differences.

Comment: [The behavior becomes apparent once you increase the size of the lists](https://tio.run/##tVLNTsMwDL7nKUy5JCIbawsSmtQnqSoUVI9FStMq9Qo8fbEbLgPEjRwSx/H3YyvTB53HWK@rH6YxEZAf0JNSCecSmq/rPh9aFUWh/AlcCDpg1J5wMNA0UMJpTCBX8BF6R84cFfBimksgJmo7hWHGnJ3JJUlGfCftM9bCIliMlwGTI9QbC7CaKC0GbljGbHCMPYMlnWt2fxMlXDDN2Ofqn5TXRqWo3QweWaeTlq2akS5TU8gbl@i2rbtN7FmUkouvqKsDL9MZuAN5ttCW9lGOLa5tZR8keMqpjknZ4AumplZsQeZd/T7vt7MPmLttD10edx5jv5/GSR8M3LL9YVwQTmkc4IyuV1ewXfkL7juMnA/X3f5Pq1PykbT8LytTr7a9vJfQrOsn).

Comment: Makes sense, time for my code to be 5 times slower :P

Comment: Are you sure you need to check `if start == -1:`? I believe if you have `result = data[-1: end]` it will always give you an empty list. Also, a style point, but instead of `range(len(data) - 1, -1, -1)` I'd use `reversed(range(len(data))`, much more readable IMO

Comment: Your benchmark is broken. The third solution modifies the list, reducing it to almost nothing. So for the second to seventh attempt it barely has anything to do.

Comment: Oh, looks like actually @ForceBru introduced that bug.

Comment: You make it sound like the generators are slower. They're actually faster (due to `enumerate` being faster than indexing).

Comment: @KellyBundy, indeed, the setup statement is only executed [once](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#timeit.Timer.timeit), so looks like my code modifies this list and is then run on that same modified list. Well, these are some broken benchmarks of mine... Apparently, the "slowdowns" were due to the mutation of `d`. I fixed this, and now even my original claim of a 9 times slowdown seems invalid

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the suggestion; edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply keep track of the indices where the condition is met and then slice your list accordingly, instead of modifying the list.

```
def filter_list(list_of_list, len_to_filter):
    l, r = 0, -1  # left, right indices
    while len(list_of_list[l]) == len_to_filter:
        l += 1
    while len(list_of_list[r]) == len_to_filter:
        r -= 1
    if r == -1:  # avoid case where r + 1 is 0
        return list_of_list[l:]
    else:
        return list_of_list[l : r + 1]

filter_list(d, 1)
```

This doesn't mutate the original list and does not require any sorting or reversal. You just traverse the list from each side until a different size than the expected one is reached.

Here is a benchmark comparing it to `pop`, if there are few lists with the required length to remove, the `version` and indices versions are pretty much the same. If there are a lot of lists with the required length to filter, to `pop` operations become non-negligible and the indices version is better.

```py
import random

small = [[3], [1, 5], [3], [3, 2, 4], [8], [3]]
# create 10_000 lists of length 1 or 2
ll = [
    [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 2))]
    for _ in range(10_000)
]

worst_case = [
    [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 1))]
    for _ in range(10_000)
]

worst_case[5000] = [1, 2, 3]


def filter_pop(list_of_list, len_to_filter):
    while len(list_of_list[0]) == len_to_filter:
        list_of_list.pop(0)

    while len(list_of_list[-1]) == len_to_filter:
        list_of_list.pop()

    return list_of_list


def filter_list(list_of_list, len_to_filter):
    l, r = 0, -1  # left, right indices
    while len(list_of_list[l]) == len_to_filter:
        l += 1
    while len(list_of_list[r]) == len_to_filter:
        r -= 1
    if r == -1:  # avoid case where r + 1 is 0
        return list_of_list[l:]
    else:
        return list_of_list[l : r + 1]
```

```
In [208]: %timeit -n100 filter_pop(ll[:], 1)
47.6 µs ± 9.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [209]: %timeit -n100 filter_pop(worst_case[:], 1)
7.46 ms ± 71.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [210]: %timeit -n100 filter_list(ll, 1)
43.7 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [211]: %timeit -n100 filter_list(worst_case, 1)
1 ms ± 59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Think you mean `filter_list` at the bottom.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I added some benchmark as well

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple solution:

```
def removeFunction(d):
    l = 0
    r = len(d) - 1
    
    # remove length 1 elements from beginning
    for i in range(len(d)):
        if len(d[i]) > 1:
            l = i
            break
            
    # remove length 1 elements from the end
    for i in range(len(d)-1, -1, -1):
        if len(d[i]) > 1:
            r = i
            break
            
    return d[l:r+1]
```

Comment: `removeFunction([[1]])` raises `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I have fixed the error thank you @ForceBru

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `i` or `n` since you're modifying the list, so its first and last elements change, not their indices. You can do something along these lines:

```
while d and len(d[0]) == 1:
    d.pop(0) # remove from head

while d and len(d[-1]) == 1:
    d.pop() # remove from tail
```

Comment: I added a benchmark as well, which seems to perform better when there are a lot of removals

Comment: 1 query - for time complexity, don't you think reversing the list and doing `pop()` is simpler than `pop(0)` ?

Comment: @sam I wasn't trying to write particularly fast code. My goal was to articulate the concept of using `push/pop` instead of indices since this leads to code that's easier to understand.

Comment: One possible optimization that doesn't need more code and would keep it about as easy: Remove from tail first. Then removing from head might have less shifting to do. In the extreme case of all sublists having length 1, this even changes it from quadratic time to linear time.

Answer (score 0):

remove() removes the first encountered element given in the function paramater.

So in your case your code that removes the last element first checks the elements from beginning of the list, because of that it removes [3] from middle.

For that part you can use pop() or del which removes the element from given index:

```
while len(d[n-1]) == 1:
    d.pop()
    n = n - 1
```

**Note:** You can use pop() without an argument in this case, because it removes last item from the list when there is no given argument.

Comment: The last code raises `IndexError` for `d = [[3], [1,5], [3], [3,2,4], [8], [3], [3]]`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I will scan the list only once to find the start and end of the sublist:

```py
def remove_ends(li):
    start = end = len(li)
    for index, element in enumerate(li):
        if len(element) != 1:
            start = min(start, index)
            end = index + 1
    return li[start:end]
```

This code works against the following test cases:

```
>>> remove_ends([[1]])
[]

>>> remove_ends([[1], [2]])
[]

>>> remove_ends([[1,2], [3,4], [5], [6,7]])
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6, 7]]

>>> remove_ends([[1], [2], [3], [1, 5], [3], [3, 2, 4], [8], [3]])
[[1, 5], [3], [3, 2, 4]]

>>> remove_ends([])
[]

>>> remove_ends([[1,2]])
[[1, 2]]
```